# Extract data from a Matrix into a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I would like to know if tehre is any way to extract the data from a matrix to create a single vector, but having the data extracted from rows (not columns).

AS an example, assume I have this matrix:

```
  [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  253  195
 [2,]   30   16
 [3,]  109   89
 [4,]  369  328
 [5,] 1895 1731
 [6,]   45   23
 [7,]   39   35
 [8,]   29   33
 [9,]  625  565
[10,]    4    6
[11,]  209  162
```

and, as a final result, I want this vector, with extrapolated data one row at a time:

```
y<-c(235,195,30,16,109,89,369,328,1895,1731,
     45,23,39,35,29,35,625,565,4,6,209,162)
```

Is there any code to do so rather than doing it manually?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `c(t(mat))` ...